# How to include multiple extra columns in Pandas Dataframe using groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a Pandas dataframe using some extra columns from the original dataset. I am using "groupby" to create my needed groups:

```
icetest_data_grouped = icetest_data.groupby(
    by=['competition', 
        'origcode', 
        'groupno'])
  .size().reset_index(name='groupsize')
```

I also want to include another column from the original dataset, called "created", and select the max-value of that column for the group:

```
icetest_data_grouped.max()['created'].reset_index(name='timestamp')
```

However, that throws error `Unable to open 'hashtable_class_helper.pxi': File not found`.

How do I achieve the desired output?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Seems like you may need [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)

Comment: Thanks, Alollz, that solved my problem.